# Flip and Rotate image. Affine Transform doesn't work correctly in java

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, flip, affinetransform

Hey i implement code to **rotate AND flip** image.

- Left, Right, Upsidedown rotation works.
- Fliping Horizontal, Vertical works.
- But they dont work together

When i flip image and then i rotate, it disappears.

BUT

When i flip and flip image (so it is as it was before flip) i can rotate normally.

---

I try to understand what is wrong and i think the problem is with transform or scale.

Do you have any idea how to fix this code ?

```
/**
 * Paint the icons of this compound icon at the specified location
 * 
 * @param c
 *            The component on which the icon is painted
 * @param g
 *            the graphics context
 * @param x
 *            the X coordinate of the icon's top-left corner
 * @param y
 *            the Y coordinate of the icon's top-left corner
 */
@Override
public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    AffineTransform af = g2.getTransform();
    int cWidth = icon.getIconWidth() / 2;
    int cHeight = icon.getIconHeight() / 2;

    int xAdjustment = (icon.getIconWidth() % 2) == 0 ? 0 : -1;
    int yAdjustment = (icon.getIconHeight() % 2) == 0 ? 0 : -1;

    if (rotate == Rotate.DOWN) {

        g2.translate(x + cHeight, y + cWidth);
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
        icon.paintIcon(c, g2, -cWidth, yAdjustment - cHeight);

    } else if (rotate == Rotate.UP) {

        g2.translate(x + cHeight, y + cWidth);
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(-90));
        icon.paintIcon(c, g2, xAdjustment - cWidth, -cHeight);

    } else if (rotate == Rotate.UPSIDE_DOWN) {

        g2.translate(x + cWidth, y + cHeight);
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(180));
        icon.paintIcon(c, g2, xAdjustment - cWidth, yAdjustment - cHeight);

    } else if (rotate == Rotate.VERTICAL) { 

         g2.translate(0, getIconHeight());  
         g2.scale(1, -1); 

         icon.paintIcon(c, g2, x, y); 
         vert = !vert; //boolean flag

    } else if (rotate == Rotate.HORIZONTAL) {

        g2.translate(getIconWidth(), 0);  
        g2.scale(-1, 1);  
        icon.paintIcon(c, g2, x, y); 
        hor = !hor; //boolean flag

    } else if (rotate == Rotate.VERTICALLY_HORIZONTAL) {

        g2.translate(getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());  
        g2.scale(-1, -1);  
        icon.paintIcon(c, g2, x, y);
        hor = !hor;
        vert = !vert;

    } else if (rotate == Rotate.CENTER) {

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        AffineTransform original = g2.getTransform();
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.concatenate(original);
        at.translate((getIconWidth() - icon.getIconWidth()) / 2,
                (getIconHeight() - icon.getIconHeight()) / 2);
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), x + cWidth, y + cHeight);
        g2.setTransform(at);
        icon.paintIcon(c, g2, x, y);
        g2.setTransform(original);

    }
}
```

Comment: After `icon.paintIcon` one needs to restore the original state of `g2` , doing the inverse operations.

Comment: Maybe but i try to do this inverse operations when boolean flag vert was set true:
  if(vert) {
    g2.translate(0, getIconHeight());  
    g2.scale(1, -1);
  }

Comment: Anybody know how to inverse it mathematicly ?

Comment: `g2.scale(1, -1); g2.translate(0, -getIconHeight());`

Comment: well when there is a vertical flip i set boolean flag "vert" and in if block for rotating LEFT (up) and DOWN (right) i do this inversion before normal translate and rorate and it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe test thins in simoler, reduced code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to work together you've got to save the image you've made with your transform. Here is an example

`Image orig = ...;
Image transformedCopy = ...;
AffineTransformation at = ...;
transformedCopy.getGraphics().setTransform(at).drawImage(orig);
//transformedCopy will now have a copy of the transformed image`

Comment: Yes but, Im using ImageIcon so what i have to save:
-ImageIcon
-Graphics2D
-Graphics
-Icon 

?

Comment: ImageIcon.setImage(transformedCopy);